# When Iterating a MATLAB loop, it doesn't iterate up to the specified value -- Why?

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, max

the loop:

```
for h=1:t_max
    REST OF CODE
end
```

if t_max is equal to 100, for example, the loop iterates only to 99 or t_max-1.

Anybody can help?

Comment: You need to provide more details.  `for h=1:10; display(h); end` prints 10 times, as expected.

Comment: we can't help if you hide `REST OF CODE` from us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is t_max a computed value? It may be ending up very close to 100 but not quite there, and due to rounding it would display as 100 in the default format setting. Here's an example using a smaller value of t_max:

```
>> t_max=4.9999999999999     

t_max =

    5.0000
```

Note how t_max looks like it's 5 when it's really a shade smaller than 5. In a for loop it would behave like this:

```
>> for i=1:t_max, disp(i),end
     1

     2

     3

     4
```

which has the appearance of only iterating to t_max - 1. But bumping up the format, and looking at t_max again will show the value with more precision:

```
>> format long; t_max

t_max =

   4.999999999999900
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not modifying t_max in the body of the loop. The semantics of the for loop is such that it will execute t_max times, check the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-1931.html#brbss8u-1).

Comment: The matrix that is iterated over is computed at the start of the for loop operation and modifying the value or values used to compute it in the body of the for loop have no effect on the loop. Try for example `t=5;for i=1:t, t=10; disp(i); end`, you'll see it only goes up to 5, not 10.